UNO R4, cannot open dfu device
New UNO R4 Minima,  Aduino IDE 2.3.2 AppImage,  Linux Fedora 40
Blink example compiles, but fails to upload.  Tried swapping cables, ports, rebooted, reset twice fails to produce a dfu port.
Here are the messages from the attempted build and upload:
Sketch uses 38780 bytes (14%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Global variables use 3940 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 28828 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 32768 bytes.
dfu-util 0.11-arduino4

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2021 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

dfu-util: Cannot open DFU device 2341:0069 found on devnum 14 (LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS)
dfu-util: No DFU capable USB device available
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 74


Well. how about that.  2 down votes, and my first post on arduino.  And, not a word of explanation or opportunity to respond.   I was hoping this group would be better than the other stack exchanges.    I stopped contributing in other forums and will stop here too.  That sort of behavior makes the forum unwelcoming and not worth my time.

The answer to the question is that the user does not have privileges to access the device.  It turns out that is the meaning of the exit status 74.
The solution, as kindly provided by ptillisch here is a missing udev rules file.
With an editor, echo, or any means you like, create this file:
/etc/udev/rules.d/60-arduino.rules

and give it the following single line of content:
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", MODE:="0666"

After creating this file, run the following two commands:
# sudo udevadm trigger
# sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

